# Design a context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

`L(G) = {x^n # y^m | 0 <= 2m <= n <= 4m}`

How would I design a context free grammar for the above language where S is the start state?

I am not sure how to get a single pound sign in the middle. 
My approach : `S => xxxxSy | B | C | epsilon , B =>xxxBy, C => xxCy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine two easier languages: x^2m # y^m, and x^4m # y^m. What do CFGs for these look like?

```
T := xxTy | #

F := xxxxFy | #
```

The languages generated by each of these grammars is a subset of our language. In fact, we can get pretty close by just combining T and F into one start symbol, S:

```
S := xxxxSy | xxSy | #
```

This is very close, however, it does not let us generate a prefix of x of odd length. We can fix this by allowing one extra x to be added during the `S := xxSy` rule and remembering that we already did this by switching to a new nonterminal `R`:

```
S := xxxxSy | xxSy | xxxRy | #
R := xxxxRy | xxRy | #
```

We can now show this grammar works by induction:

Base case: the string # (for m = n = 0) is in the language. The next shortest strings in the language are xx#y, xxx#y and xxxx#y, as required.

Induction hypothesis: exactly the required strings are in the language for all m up to and including k.

Induction step: we must show that all required strings are in the language for m = k + 1. We know that all required strings are in the language for y = k; so we have x^2k # y, …, x^4k # y. Adding an extra y to the end means we need at least two extra x on the front (so our minimum is now x^2k+2 # y^(k+1)) and at most we can add four extra x (so our maximum is now x^4k+4 # y^(k+1)). The only "new" numbers of x we introduced were x^4k+1, x^4k+2, x^4k+3 and x^4k+4, and we can get these as follows:

1. changing out one application of `S := xxxxSy` in the derivation of `x^4k # y^k` for `S := xxxRy` and one of `R := xxRy` gives us `x^4k+1 # y^(k+1)`.
2. adding one application of `S := xxSy` in the derivation of `x^4k # y^k` gives us `x^4k+2 # y^(k+1)`.
3. adding one application of `S := xxxRy` in the derivation of `x^4k # y^k` gives us `x^4k+3 # y^(k+1)`.
4. adding one application of `S := xxxxSy` in the derivation of `x^4k # y^k` gives us `x^4k+4 # y^(k+1)`.

Comment: If you remove `R`, changing the production where it is used to use `S` instead of `R`, what undesirable sentence is accepted? Or what desired sentence is rejected?

Comment: @rici Probably none. Not sure exactly why I did this now. Maybe at first I was thinking of adding a production like `S := xR` to change the parity by adding a single `x` and then went to `S := xxxRy` since it makes more sense but didn't make the final leap that having a second nonterminal was unnecessary with this change.